# path url split() find() angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have urls and I want to recover the beginning of the path but I don't know how to do it and being a beginner according to my research I should use the split() and find() method.

Here are the urls:

**/test/someurls**

**/angular/someurls**

I need to get **/test** and **/angular** is it possible to do that?

Thanks in advance.

```
ngOnInit() {

 let firstUrl: string = '/test/someurls';
 let secondUrl:string = '/angular/someurls';

 let t = firstUrl.split(" ").find(element =>element.startWith('/test');
    console.log(t);
}
```

Comment: have you made an attempt? please share your attempt and issues you face

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code using split function.

```
function getBeginning(a) {
  return "/" + a.split("/")[1];
}
console.log(getBeginning("/test/some"));
console.log(getBeginning("/angular/some"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another interesting way with `Angular` api:

```
const urlTree = this.router.parseUrl('/angular/someurls');


...
getBeginningFromUrlTree(urlTree: UrlTree): string {
  return `/${urlTree.root.children.primary.segments[0].path}`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
crumbs = this.router.url.split('/');

constructor(private router: Router) {}
```

Something like this ?